# I am trying to subtract a date from todays date but it is telling me the operand type is unsupported in python

Tags: python, datetime, math

Both types of data have been converted into dates, and it still is telling me it can't subtract them. I've watched many tutorials and looked at stack overflow for hours, but all the solutions say that the only possible problem is an incorrect form of data which is not true. The error message is :

```
>unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'<
```

The text file contains only this:

Birthday 30/5/2021

```
def display():
    with open ('countdown.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            data = line.split(' ')
            title = data[0]
            date_str = data[1]
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d/%m/%y') 
            time_between = datetime.date.today()-date
            print(title + 'is' + time_between + 'days away!')
display()
```

Comment: "Both types of data have been converted into dates" No, one is a `datetime.datetime` and the other is a `datetime.date`.

Answer (score 0):

One value is date+time and one is date only, they do not match. Replace `datetime.date.today()` with `datetime.datetime.today()`.

The result will be a `datetime.timedelta` object.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different `date` methods, one in `datetime` and one in `date`:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.today()
print(dt, type(dt))
# 2020-12-10 20:45:20.661116 <class 'datetime.datetime'>

d = datetime.date.today()
print(d, type(d))
# 2020-12-10 <class 'datetime.date'>
```

As your `date` is a datetime object, you need to subtract it with another datetime, so you have to use:

```
time_between = datetime.datetime.today() - date
```